# Get int from column by using email to identify row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get and echo a users permission level.

I have a function where the users email is passed, the function then needs to get the users permission level and return it, so it can be echoed on another page.

I imagine the function will look though the database for the passed email, it then finds the users permission and returns with that.

#### In the 'User.class.php'

```
public static function permGetter($email)
{
    try
    {
        $db = Database::getInstance();

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT permission FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->execute([':permission'=>$permission]);

        $user = $stmt->fetchObject('User');
        if($user !== false)
        {
            return $permission;
        }
    }

    catch (PDOException $exception)
    {
        error_log($exception->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### In the 'permRequest.php'

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("../includes/init.php");

//Get passed from an external program
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];

if($email && $pass !== null)
{
    // Checks if the user's entered credential matches with those in database
    if(Auth::getInstance()->login($email, $pass))
        {
        //Uses the passed email to get permission level in 'User.class.php'
        if(User::permGetter($email))
        {
                    echo 'Permission ' + (int) $permission;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //I use level 5 as a debug so i can see when it fails
        echo 'Permission 5';
    }
}

?>
```

#### Database

[image: example of the database layout]

Here's an example on what my database looks like.

### Edit 1

Okay messing about, I think i got closer to the solution.
First, @Lawrence Cherone, thanks for pointing out my mistake in my execute.

Okay I have changed my code in

#### User.class.php

```
public static function permGetter($email, $permission)
{
    try
    {
        $db = Database::getInstance();

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT permission FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute([':email'=>$email]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $permission = $row['permission'];
    }

    catch (PDOException $exception)
    {
        error_log($exception->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have made small changes to

#### permRequest.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("../includes/init.php");

//Get passed from an external program
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$permission = '';

if($email && $pass !== null)
{
    // Checks if the user's entered credential matches with those in database
    if(Auth::getInstance()->login($email, $pass))
    {
    //Uses the passed email to get permission level in 'User.class.php'
        if(User::permGetter($email, $permission))
        {
            echo 'Permission ', $permission;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

But now i get an error. The error is this `Notice: Undefined index: permission in /classes/User.class.php on line 56`

So, I read up on it and it seemed like it should be emptied first, so I empty it in `permRequest.php` that's why I'm passing it too, but I still get this error after i emptied it?

However if i change

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

to

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/*         OR         */
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

I get no error but it simply says my email or password is incorrect, which it isn't I have double and triple checked it.

So I'm confused to which `PDO::FETCH_` I should use. I have read this ([Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)) and I would say that both `ASSOC`, `BOTH` and `NUM` would fit the purpose.

So why is one giving an error while the two other's simply fails the login?

### Edit 2

Found the solution and i have written it as a Answer. Can't accept it for the next two days however.

Comment: `:permission` != `:email`, check your query.

Comment: Also for the love of cats, don't pass passwords as GET params.

Comment: And would assume it's `return $user->permission;`

Answer (score 0):

I moved everything out of the `User.class.php` and moved it into `permRequest.php`. This solved my problem for some reason. So my code looks like this now

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require_once("../includes/init.php");

$email = $_GET['email'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];

if($email && $pass !== null)
{
    if(Auth::getInstance()->login($email, $pass))
    {

        try
        {
            $db = Database::getInstance();

            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
            $stmt->execute([':email' => $email]);
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $sub = $row['permission'];

            echo 'Permission ', $sub;

        }
        catch (PDOException $exception)
        {
            error_log($exception->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't use the `User.class.php` for this function.

So my guess is something went wrong when returning `$sub` when it was in `User.class.php`